# Cutting plane method vs. ellipsoid problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Why is cutting plane (centroid) algorithm an order of $n$ faster than the Ellipsoid method? I am referring to the number of iterations / queries to the separating oracle that they make.
I know in ellipsoid it is $ O(n^2 * log(R/r)) $ while Cutting Plane makes $ O(n* log(R/r)) $ queries to the oracle. Why is it faster than Ellipsoid? They seem to work similarly.

Comment: Some links to references for the algorithms might help. You didn't even say what problem they're supposed to solve.

Comment: They solve optimization problems. I'm not looking for an answer to a specific optimization question (just a general understanding of why one is faster than the other).

Comment: You're making the huge unjustified assumption that someone will read your question and have any idea what you're writing about. In order to explain how fast an algorithm is, one should first know what algorithm you have in mind. "The cutting plane method" is only a little more informative than "the algorithm my prof showed in the last lecture."

Comment: Regarding Ellipsoid method, a quick google search would have brought https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method which is the ellipsoid method I am referring to. Ellipsoid method can apply to a much more general class of problems, but I am looking at how it solves Linear Programs. Here are more resources which all talk about Ellipsoid method in the context of solving LP: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos521/ellipsoid.pdf, http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/ellipsoid.pdf

Comment: Regarding the cutting plane method, it is also known as the centroid cutting plane, which you can read more about here: https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/05-localization_methods_notes.pdf . Here is another good resource on Ellipsoid method: https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vempala/acg/www/18.433/L1617.pdf

Comment: Sure, I could Google "ellipsoid method," but until _you told me_ I had no way to know whether that would show me the same method _you_ were using. Glad to see you now have a relevant answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ellipsoid method the constraint is always in the form of an ellipsoid, while in cutting plane methods, linear inequalities are used to form a polyhedral set.  The algorithms are fundamentally different in that respect.

There are several different cutting plane methods depending on what point is used to determine the cut.  Many of them, such as the widely used analytic center cutting plane method (ACCPM) and the maximum volume ellipsoid method also have the $n^{2}$ factor in the running time.

The center of gravity (CG) method mentioned in the Boyd lecture notes does reduce this to a factor of $n$, but finding the center of gravity isn't something that can actually be done in practice for problems of interesting dimension.  This is discussed in Boyd's lecture notes.